# Thermodynamics of Acid Base Neutralisation

Tags: acid-base, thermodynamics

I was attempting an exam in which they questioned us about the thermodynamics of acid-base reaction.
The question was this:

> In neutralisation reaction of a strong acid and a strong base in a solution, the following statements are correct

and then they gave these four options

> 1. ∆*G* = negative
> 2. ∆*H* = negative
> 3. ∆*S* = negative
> 4. ∆*U* = negative

We can easily see that Option 1 and 2 are correct, but in the key, it has been specified that Option 3 as well as 4 are correct, too.
Can anyone please explain this to me.

Comment: Sorry, but can you please elaborate upon your statement

Comment: As $\Delta G =\Delta H - T\Delta S$ option (1) is always correct. As $\Delta H = \Delta U +p\Delta V$ and as volume change is negligible  $\Delta U \equiv \Delta H$. As long as $\Delta G $ is negative $\Delta H $ and $\Delta S$ can be positive or negative.

Comment: @porphyrin Ok, So ∆U is negative too but how would you explain ∆S.

Comment: Suppose that the reaction is $\ce{Na+OH- + H+Cl- \to H2O + Na+Cl-}$ then you may argue that entropy is reduced as initially there are 4 species and finally only 3 since all are fully dissociated except water which is only partially so. If this is true then $\Delta H $ must be more negative than $T\Delta S$ is positive to make $\Delta G$ negative.

Comment: @porphyrin Ok, I understood your Reasoning. Thanks